# How to access Javascript function using JSR223 Sampler in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have a `Javascript` function in `JSR223 Sampler` and I would like to call this function in my `HTTP Request sampler`. Any idea how to call the function?

Example:

I know I can do something like this and use the "`total`" variable from my `HTTP Request Sampler`.

```
var total;
function sum(a, b){
    return a+b;
};
vars.put("total", sum(2,4));
```

But is there a way to call the function `sum(a,b)` directly from `HTTP Request sampler`? If not, is there any other way to do this? A sample example will really help me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, are you aware of [__intSum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) which does exactly what you're trying to achieve, the syntax would be:

```
${__intSum(2,4,total)}
```

---

If you still want to proceed with coding:

1. Don't use JavaScript as it might become a performance bottleneck. [Since JMeter 3.1 it is strongly recommended to use Groovy for scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html).
2. Create a file, i.e. `sum.groovy` in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   int sum (int a, int b) {
       return a + b;
   }
   ```
3. Run JMeter as follows:

   ```
   jmeter -Jgroovy.utilities=sum.groovy
   ```

   If you want to make the change permanent - add the relevant line to *user.properties* file

   ```
   groovy.utilities=sum.groovy
   ```

   See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more detailed information on setting and overriding JMeter properties
4. You will be able to sum numbers with [__groovy function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

   ```
   ${__groovy(sum(2\, 4),total)}
   ```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of `__intSum()` function.  I just gave an example. Anyway, thank you for your answer. I didn't know that we are not supposed to use JS.